# Is It Possible To Find Term NOT Near Other Term?

Tags: marklogic

I was expecting to be able to write a common search query that looks for one word but only when it is not near another word. In typical search grammar, it might look like this:

```
Christmas NOT WITHIN/3 father
```

In this case, I want to find "Christmas" but not when it is very close to the word "father".

I thought MarkLogic could do this, but I am not finding any examples of that ability.

Does anybody know if it IS supported somehow, and if not is there a way to "hack it" easily?

I support I could just do a preliminary search for "Christmas", and count the number of hits. then do a search for "Christmas" NEAR "father", and count those too, then ignore a document when the counts are the same - but I prefer not to take this long-winded approach if I can avoid it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** See "PROTOTYPE" below. A few notes are about assumptions and speculation, so I have updated with a re-useable sample to test query strings against phrases.

**UPDATE** updated query to be a not in query

You do not state how you are searching. However, the way you wrote the query, I am assuming using an interface to the search library and use of [String Queries](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/string-query)

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";


let $phrases := (
  "This has Christmas and Christmas and over here it has Father. However, Father is too far away from Christmas for us to care",
  "Christmas is all alone here",
  "Sometimes there is a sentance in which Father and Christmas are too close  -but no reference to those words elsewhere",
  "Sometimes there is a sentance in which Christmas and Father are too close(and reversed)  -but no reference to those words elsewhere",
  "Sometimes Father Christmas are too close and Christmas is also referenced on its own"
)

let $string-query := 'Christmas NOT_IN (Christmas NEAR/2[unordered] Father)'

let $query := cts:parse($string-query)

return for $phrase in $phrases
  let $match := if(cts:contains($phrase, $query)) then "MATCH :: " else "NO MATCH :: "
  return $match || $phrase
```

Result:

```
MATCH :: This has Christmas and Christmas and over here it has Father. However, Father is too far away from Christmas for us to care

MATCH :: Christmas is all alone here

NO MATCH :: Sometimes there is a sentance in which Father and Christmas are too close  -but no reference to those words elsewhere

NO MATCH :: Sometimes there is a sentance in which Christmas and Father are too close(and reversed)  -but no reference to those words elsewhere

MATCH :: Sometimes Father Christmas are too close and Christmas is also referenced on its own
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that would not find a document containing "Christmas" though. But I suppose I could add a clause to find "Christmas" first. This looks promising.

Comment: Correct.. If the problem statement is christmas as long as it is not near father, then you need to ask that question "Christmas -(Christmas NEAR/3 father)"

Comment: @NeilBradley - I updated the sample to match your problem statement better.

Comment: This assumes there is at most one instance of Christmas per document, right? I think currently it fails to find documents that contain “Christmas” both near and not near “Father”. Is that the desired behaviour?  Would merging the `and` and `not` into an `and-not-query` help?

Comment: It makes no assumption of only one occurrence of the word Christmas. However, tuning of that is possible with additional query options (min and max occurrence of a word or phrase).  Also, and-not-query is just a shortcut. The logic above is the same and(Christmas , NOT(christmas near father))  -- In all cases, I have updated the sample with ar re-usable piece of code to tune the query against phrases in order to experiment

Comment: Thanks for all your input. Unfortunately, I WOULD want a match on the fourth phrase, because it does contain an instance of "Christmas" that is not near "father".  It is beginning to look like this quite common query option in other platforms (including Google) is not available directly in MarkLogic, which is s a great shame.

Comment: My fall-back plan would take 4 steps:

1. find all documents that contain "Christmas"
2. in each of those documents, count the matches on "Christmas"
3. also count matches on "Christmas" near "father"
4. compare the counts - if the counts are the same, then there are no instances of "Christmas" that are not near "father"

Any better ideas still welcome of course!

Comment: " I WOULD want a match on the fourth phrase, because it does contain an instance of "Christmas""  

Of the four statemns, which should match - and do you have others as well as samples?

Comment: I simply want to find all instances of "Christmas" that are not near "father". Just like in Google and in other search engines.

Comment: By the way, I am aware of the "not-in" option, where I can find "Christmas" but not in "father Christmas", and I may have to use that technique instead, but of course it is more limited in its scope (it would ignore "Christmas father" for example)

Comment: This has been an interesting challenge.  I went back to CTS and worked the problem back.  NIT_IN matched with a near query marked as unordered (terms in any order) appear to work as I interpret the question.